# auto-updating date field in word template, that stops updating after save

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I want to add a date field to letter template in Word 2003 (windows version).

However, I want to update it only when the *template* is opened - I don't want to auto-update it in the *resulting file*, when it is opened, let's say, month later.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `CreateDate` field does what you are asking, as long as you are using a proper `.dot` template file and not a standard `.doc` that is opened and re-saved.

Note that you will have to manually update the field (eg, select it and press <kbd>F9</kbd> or use the right-click menu) to get it refresh - but it should show the creation date of the derived document, and not the template.

Add fields by using **Insert** - **Field...** on the menu bar, select **Date and Time** in the *Categories* box to make this easier to find.

Comment: yes, this is it